# Using this.state for assigning a property to HTML tag

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working on a project where the graph is supposed to show the name (string) of the Y Axis according to the chosen graph type.

I tried declaring it in state as

```
this.state = {
    yAxisLabel: 'Acceleration',
};
```

and using it in the HTML tag as below.

```
<div>
  <YAxis
      label={{value: {this.state.yAxisLabel},
           offset: -3,
           angle: -90,
           position: 'left',
      }}
 />
</div>
```

I have tried declaring a const string variable with a string and passing it, that too didn't work.

```
const yAxisLabelName = 'Acceleration';
```

and using it as

```
<div>
  <YAxis
      label={{value: {yAxisLabelName},
           offset: -3,
           angle: -90,
           position: 'left',
      }}
 />
</div>
```

I have tried searching over the internet and also over stackoverflow, but couldn't find a similar question.

Could someone please let me know if it is possible. And if yes, a correct way to approach this problem.

PS: New to react, but have googled a lot before asking

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Please add more details such as which library you are using to render graphs.

Comment: @GaneshKrishna I am using Recharts library. Specifically,[link](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis) this page might provide the exact tag. If there is anymore info I could provide, please let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove curly brackets around `this.state.yAxisLabel`.

Comment: Very thank you for that quick find. I feel extremely stupid to have missed that. Thanks a lot mate, cheers.